# Windows 10 Log into VPN before Sign in Error

Tags: windows-10, vpn

Ok so I have enabled Ctrl Alt Delete login on policy settings. I get the icon before logging in to connect to my VPN. I can log into the VPN successfully but right after I connect it says wrong username and password and wont give me the option to log into my domain account after connecting the VPN any ideas?

Comment: What VPN client are you using?

Comment: Built In windows to connect to a Meraki Router

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if Windows has cached the credentials and you've changed your password recently. You may need to log into your computer with the previous password even though the VPN accepts the new password.

Comment: I gave that a shot no luck. When the logon screen comes up I press the vpn connection logo then type my VPN Creditials it connects but then kicks back wrong sign in. I thought I first connect the VPN after that then log in with my domain credentials is this not a two step process?